# Polymorphism and Inheritance in Angular Objects

Tags: angular

I'm new to Angular and have been trying to do a simple polymorphic program with Rectangle, Circle, and Triangle objects that inherit from a larger Shape object in such a way that Rectangle, Circle, and Triangle are all considered Shapes. Is this something that is possible to do in Angular, and if so how do I go about accomplishing it?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. This question is a bit vague, which bit are you stuck on? The syntax? The general concept?

Comment: See [MDN JavaScript Reference - Classes - extends](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/extends)

Comment: I wonder what do you mean by *angular objects*; components? services?
Classes and inheritance in typescript work as in most OO languages, and its unrelated to angular.

Answer (score 0):

You can use classes to define a Shape class that is extended by the three Shapes. I would handle it like so:

```
class Circle extends Shape {
private radius: number;
color: string;

constructor(shape) {
    super(shape);
    if (shape.type = circle)
    this.radius = shape.radius;
    this.color = shape.color;
}
```

Here is an article that explains the concept well https://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/extending-classes-and-interfaces-using-typescript